# "Postman -How to check the typeof any key is 'string' or 'null' at same time"

Tags: javascript, postman, postman-testcase

In given response snippet "parentName" type is sometimes `null` or sometimes `string`. How to check/write testcase to check the typeof `string` as well as `null` at a time.

```
tests["Verify parentName is string"] = typeof(jsonData.parentName) === "string" || null;

tests["Verify parentName is string"] = typeof(jsonData.parentName) === "string" || "null";
```

```
"demo": [
            {
                "id": 68214,
                "specializationId": 286,
                "name": "Radiology",
                "parentName": null,
                "primary": true
            }
        ],
```

How to handle this kind of condition in postman (null & string).

Comment: Are you trying to write code in javascript to identify the type?

Comment: Yes I am trying to write code in js

Comment: so you can do - `jsonData.parentName === null || typeof jsonData.parentName === 'string'`

Comment: @Kaushik i tried this and its works for me. But then i just change the type from 'string' to number(just for testing purpose) `jsonData.parentName === null || typeof jsonData.parentName === 'number'` still it's result showing pass. It should be fail right.

Comment: you can try using `if elsif and else` block probably.

Comment: @Akshay77: I would not recommend if else if in Postman test case, check below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not recommend *if elseif* in Postman test case. Postman has inbuilt feature for schema checking, you can use that and can achieve the same result without if else.

First, I'm considering following as a response:

```
{
    "demo": [{
        "id": 68214,
        "specializationId": 286,
        "name": "Radiology",
        "parentName": null,
        "primary": true
    }]
}
```

Postman test should be:

```
var Ajv = require('ajv'),
ajv = new Ajv({logger: console}),
schema = {
    "properties": {
        "parentName": {
            "type":["string", "null"]
        }
    }
};

pm.test('Verify parentName is string', function() {    
    var resParentName =  pm.response.json().demo[0].parentName;
    pm.expect(ajv.validate(schema, {parentName: resParentName})).to.be.true;
});
```

**Edit:** Validate full response, not just first item. Also check if `parentName` is present in the response or not.

```
var Ajv = require('ajv'),
ajv = new Ajv({logger: console}),
schema = {
    "properties": {
        "demo":{
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                 "properties": {
                     "id":{ "type": "integer" },
                     "specializationId":{ "type": "integer" },
                     "name":{"type": "string"},
                     "parentName":{
                         "type":["string", "null"]
                     },
                     "primary":{"type": "boolean"}
                 },
                 "required": [ "parentName"]
            }
        }
    }
};

pm.test('Validate response', function() {
    pm.expect(ajv.validate(schema, pm.response.json())).to.be.true;
});
```

Comment: Hey need small help i am getting error `Error: Cannot find module 'ajv'` then  I tried `npm install ajv` but still getting same error. please tell what should i do.

Comment: @Akshay77: What is your Postman version. There is no need to install npm package

Comment: Wouldn't that only check the first object, what if there were more? If parentName was removed from the response, I'm sure that would still pass.

Comment: Thanks @DannyDainton  for pointing out the edge cases I had missed. Answer updated! Let me know if anything still missing :)